# Run useEffect Hook whenever the React-i18n language changes on localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to run `useEffect` hook, whenever the language gets changed in localStorage. currently its only returning the old selected language.I tried storage event still its not working.

```
const getLanguage = () => i18next.language || window.localStorage.i18nextLng;

  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = getLanguage();
    console.log({ storage });
  }, [window.localStorage.i18nextLng, i18next.language]);
```

Comment: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage